# Converting PHP array into JQuery data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

I have encountered a little of a problem while trying to convert PHP array into jQuery. I have read a lot of threads on forum and I still cannot figure out what's wrong.

My PHP code that's basically for adding last 7 dates into array and assigning "a" and "b" to same value just for tests

```
$dni = array();
for($i =7; $i>0; $i--){
$dzien = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i." day"));
$d->y = $dzien;
$chart = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kolejka WHERE data LIKE '$dzien' AND odbyta = '0'", $link);
while($c = mysql_fetch_array($chart, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $xdi = $c['COUNT(*)'];
}  
$d->a = $xdi;
$d->b = $xdi;
$dni[] = $d;
}
$data = json_encode($dni);
```

My jQuery code that's supposed to generate a chart:

```
var ar = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
alert(ar);
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'pacjenci-chart',
    data: ar,
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    labels: ['New', 'Old'],
    barColors: ['#33414E', '#1caf9a'],
    gridTextSize: '10px',
    hideHover: true,
    resize: true,
    gridLineColor: '#E5E5E5'
});
```

If I put into "data" a non-dynamic content like:

```
        data: [
        { y: 'Oct 10', a: 75, b: 35 },
        { y: 'Oct 11', a: 64, b: 26 },
        { y: 'Oct 12', a: 78, b: 39 },
        { y: 'Oct 13', a: 82, b: 34 },
        { y: 'Oct 14', a: 86, b: 39 },
        { y: 'Oct 15', a: 94, b: 40 },
        { y: 'Oct 16', a: 96, b: 41 }
    ],
```

It works just fine.

An output of

```
    var ar = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
```

is

```
var ar = "[{\"y\":\"2017-03-19\",\"a\":\"0\",\"b\":\"0\"},{\"y\":\"2017-03-19\",\"a\":\"0\",\"b\":\"0\"},{\"y\":\"2017-03-19\",\"a\":\"0\",\"b\":\"0\"},{\"y\":\"2017-03-19\",\"a\":\"0\",\"b\":\"0\"},{\"y\":\"2017-03-19\",\"a\":\"0\",\"b\":\"0\"},{\"y\":\"2017-03-19\",\"a\":\"0\",\"b\":\"0\"},{\"y\":\"2017-03-19\",\"a\":\"0\",\"b\":\"0\"}]";
```

Comment: Case of double encoding. Remove `json_encode()` while assigning to a variable in jQuery

Comment: Double encoding. That caused the problem.

Comment: Use only one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arent you doing json-encode twice here?

```
$data = json_encode($dni);
var ar = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Get rid of one of these and it should just work like this.

It is slightly obvious because of all the extra escape's to encode a json string again it will be converted to a string :-). Just echo the $data variable.

Answer (score -1):

You encoded the array twice - first in PHP then in jQuery.

```
var ar = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

remove `json_encode()`

```
var ar = <?php echo $data; ?>;
```